# Experimental progress: Topological phases of matter

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-field-theory, topological-order, anyons

It's been:

- 43 years since Leinaas & Myrheim's [seminal paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02727953)
- 38 years since [Wilczek coined the term *anyon*](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.49.957)
- 29 years since Moore & Read's paper on [non-Abelions in the Fractional Quantum Hall Effect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/055032139190407O)
- 17 years since the publication of [Kitaev's proposal to use anyons to realise fault-tolerant quantum computation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003491602000180)

> Could anyone tell me about the **experimental frontiers** regarding the detection of Abelian/non-Abelian anyons? Links to studies would be appreciated. Your personal opinions about the progress and future of this field would also be welcome.

I guess it's still a relatively young area of condensed matter physics with lots of exotic ideas, so we shouldn't be too impatient.

Mathematicians have also begun to lay down the theoretical foundations for higher-dimensional topological phases of matter. For instance, the next natural progression is to consider 3D systems whose localised excitations take on the form of knots (the simplest case would be that of loop-like excitations i.e. unknots).

> While the higher-dimensional framework is interesting in its own right (studying 3+1D TQFTs etc.), are there any experimental reasons for believing such phases should exist?